# Create an ionic project with a specific starting version number

Tags: angular, ionic7

This should be simple, but I cannot seem to find it...  I'm hoping someone here will know the answer...

When creating a new Ionic project using `ionic start` from the command line, you can specify pretty much everything -- the name of your app, the type (Angular, Vue, etc.), whether or not to include Cordova or Capacitor, the App ID, etc., etc...

But you cannot specify the version-number of your new app.  It always sets the version number to `0.0.1`.  I want to be able to specify my version number.  Like I said, this should be simple, but I cannot find the answer anywhere...

I'm running Ionic 7.1.1, BTW.

Thanks for any help you can give me.